# How to fill form values which come from fiddler

Tags: c#, forms, post, fiddler

I want to post data to website which is `https`. When I run my app its return the same page without post data .I'm getting this information from fiddler for  webform

```
rpslBox:postRpsl=   rpslBox:postRpsl
rpslBox:postRpsl:sourceRadioSelect= RIPE_NCC
rpslBox:postRpsl:rpslObject=    post data here
rpslBox:postRpsl:update=    Update
javax.faces.ViewState=  -8600675496086047392:1644420639838409291
```

How should I fill the  `javax.faces.ViewState`? because it is dynamic value.

Comment: You will need to grab the form field values from a previous response in order to correctly submit a valid POST request.

Comment: ım sorry can you explain more briefly? javax.faces.wiewState will change in every response how can i grab?

Comment: You simply look at the prior response.